# Using CGI to Generate both XML and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, cgi

Is it possible for the XML output of one CGI script to make use of XSLT output generated by another script? I ask mainly because I can't test it right now. Basically, I'd like to know if it's possible or valid for some `page.cgi` to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.cgi?"?>
<root>
    ...
</root>
```

And some `style.cgi` to produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I do not see any reason, why this should not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible.

Serving resources like stylesheets from server-side scripts requires a bit of work on setting the right caching headers for the response, in order to avoid the client having to re-fetch the stylesheet every time, if you care about that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not too concerned with the details, since this is pretty much just a curiosity. Something to file away in the memory banks, as it were.